# jQuery dialog call redirecting page

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I'm using the jQuery dialog plugin.

The dialog div is set up (but not opened) on page load:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#foo').dialog({autoOpen:false});
});
```

Then a hyperlink is supposed to open the dialog:

```
<a href="javascript:$('#foo').dialog('open');">Show dialogue box</a>
```

But this opens the dialog then a fraction later redirects to a page with the URL `javascript:$('#foo').dialog('open');`!

I have tried returning false:

```
<a href="javascript:$('#foo').dialog('open');return false;">Show dialogue box</a>
```

But then the link doesn't respond at all when I click on it.

I know this must be to do with one of JavaScript's infamous subtleties but I can't work it out.

Can anyone help?

Comment: You could as well provide a link to the plugin you're using because I suppose there are many.

Comment: @Robert: 99.9% it's jQuery UI's dialog: http://jqueryui.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Then a hyperlink is supposed to open the dialog:
>
> `<a href="javascript:$('#foo').dialog('open');">Show dialogue box</a>`
>
> But this opens the dialog then a fraction later redirects to a page with the URL javascript:$('#foo').dialog('open');!

That shouldn't be happening. The pseudo-protocol `javascript:` doesn't involve a page load, and certainly not one via HTTP. I don't recommend it (I'd use jQuery's `click` handler instead), but it should work.

> I have tried returning false:
>   ...
>   But then the link doesn't respond at all when I click on it.

That *also* shouldn't be happening.

Your code as quoted is fine (works here, for instance: http://jsbin.com/inixa5), so the problem must lie in some other part of the page.

**Update**: Okay, that's weird, IE6 and IE7 didn't like that; I think it's because `dialog` returns a value. You can get around that either by wrapping up your call to open the dialog in a function and doesn't explicitly return anything:

```
<a href="javascript:showDialog('#foo');">Click Me</a>
<script>
  $("#foo").dialog({autoOpen: false});
  function showDialog(selector) {
    $(selector).dialog('open');
  }
</script>
```

Or (and this is mega-hacky) by making sure the last expression in the `javascript:` block is `undefined`:

```
<a href="javascript:$('#foo').dialog('open');undefined;">Click Me</a>
<script>
  $("#foo").dialog({autoOpen: false});
</script>
```

Or by using `onclick`:

```
<a href="#" onclick="$('#foo').dialog('open'); return false;">Click Me</a>
<script>
  $("#foo").dialog({autoOpen: false});
</script>
```

But in any case, strongly recommend hooking things up with a DOM2 style event handler:

```
<a href="#" name='openSesame'>Click Me</a>
<script>
  // This _can_ be immediately after the anchor, but I'd put it in
  // a separate, since .js file for the page that you load just before
  // the closing body tag.
  $("#foo").dialog({autoOpen: false});
  $("a[name=openSesame]").click(function() {
    $("#foo").dialog('open');
    return false;
  });
</script>
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/inixa5/4) (Obviously, you can use any selector that makes sense, you don't have to give the anchor a `name` [or `id`].)

One of the nice things about this is that you can then have the anchor take the user somewhere meaningful and/or useful if JavaScript is disabled (something called [*progressive enhancement*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement)).

Comment: Long term I probably would have done this unobtrusively anyway, I was just testing the dialog plugin and got confused that it wasn't working as expected. Thanks for your detailed answer.

Comment: @David: I don't mind your saying. :-) Which website are you talking about? Broken how?

Comment: Sorry, I've been on holiday. All the text on the page extends past the vertical blue line on the right hand side.

Comment: Oh, and I mean crowdersoftware.com.

Comment: @David: Thanks for letting me know. It's weird, it doesn't do that for me on FF 3.6 (even if I use Ctrl++ to make the font larger). But there's **no question** that site is dismal and really, really needs scrapping and replacing. My CSS knowledge was truly rubbish at the time (since upgraded to... *okay*), and I shouldn't be doing design anyway (I don't have an eye for it). Thanks again for the note.

Answer (score 0):

Change the link to:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="$('#foo').dialog('open')">
   Show dialogue box
</a>
```

Best avoid putting javascript in the href.
Even better would be giving it a class and than adding a click event to it through jquery.